# removeClass not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a transition function that has an overlay screen that says "loading"

```
SM.prototype.changeScene = function(sceneName){
    $("#Loading").removeClass("hide");
    $("#loading_curtain").removeClass("offscreen");
    $("#acrcurtain").removeClass("offscreen");
    $(".loading_text").removeClass("offscreen");

    var changeMe = function(){
         //lots of loading code (2-5 seconds)
    };

    window.setTimeout(changeMe, 100);
}
```

This works fine with the setTimeout set to at least 100.  If it's removed or much less the loading screen isn't displayed.  The classes are removed properly, but it doesn't show up on screen.  Is there any reason the delay helps it show up?

Comment: you just call changeme & removeClass outside of it

Comment: what sort of dependency you have in your changeMe function? perhaps you are trying to modify an un-created element or do soemthing in case an element is hidden and he is currently on animating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript running in a browser doesn't redraw elements on the screen immediately as you change them. It generally waits until there is no more JavaScript code running.

That is why the timeout allows it to redraw, and why it doesn't redraw immediately without it.

With the timeout, the current bit of JavaScript being executed finishes up, then the browser gets a chance to redraw before the "lots of loading code" runs.

Without the timeout, JavaScript code is still actively running, so the browser waits until it finishes.

Comment: How do you explain that it doesn't work either for smaller timeouts (according to the OP)?

Comment: @FelixKling - Good point! That is something I can't explain. Whenever I've done this, even a very short 1ms timeout has been sufficient to allow a redraw. I'm not sure what is going on here that shorter timeouts are not working. Would have to see more of the code, or see it in action, to hazard a guess.

Comment: Actually if I remove all but one of the .removeClass() operations it works with a smaller value, so maybe the operations can't complete in the short time?

Comment: the render isn't finishing before the "loading stuff" happens. Are you performing synchronous ajax requests? If yes, then... *don't* and this problem will go away.